# Send email using outlook error

Tags: c#

I am trying to send email using the outlook in my c# app, works fine but i am getting this annoying popup message all the time saying,

"A program trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf"

How can I remove this message ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be configured in the trust centre for your version of Outlook - you'll want to allow programmatic access.

There is the (big) caveat with this that it would allow malicious software on your PC to send email as you, and there have been worms that have used this as a propagation method in the past.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can change the outlook settings to allow my email to send and revert it back?

Comment: That would be a security flaw if you could do it without human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

do you have to use Outlook API to do this - you can use
System.Net.Mail SmtpClient instead which will not give you this message

[sending mail as smtp client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Comment: Hi Thank you... but I have tried this before but my email exchange rejects all my request to send email.

Comment: Ok. so I think the only way is to take Rowland's approach which requires a change by your admin (if you don't have access to this) or to use an account which can send emails via your email exchange server and use SMTPclient with specific network credentials..